# Visual block append does not seem to work with Inside Paragraph (ip)

Tags: visual-block

If I select several lines in visual block mode and then append it works, for example:

```
<C-v>jjj$A;<ESC>
```

will append a semicolon to 4 lines. However if select a paragraph it does not work. For example:

```
<C-v>ip$A;<ESC>
```

does not work. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because using a text-object switches to *visual-line* mode.

Do:

```
vip<C-v>
```

instead of

```
<C-v>ip
```

See `:help ip`.